# How can wicket Page form model be accessed from child panel

Tags: wicket

Here is the hierarchy

Parent WebPage contains Panel. Webpage has a form

```java
add(this.form = new Form<LoginUser>("form", new CompoundPropertyModel<LoginUser>(new LoginUserModel(user))) {

@Override
protected void onSubmit() { 
...
}
```

Now in the Panel I need to get the updated LoginUser from form updates. In the panel I tried to get it through `((UserPage) getPage()).getForm().getModelObject();`
However, it is not giving the updated value of `LoginUser`.

Please provide your inputs on how I can get access to form model of the parent WebPage in the panel.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the Model or ModelObject to your Panel in it's constructor and store it in a member of your panel. Since it's the very same Object as the one backing your form, it will contain the same, updated values.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. In this case should i be passing the CompoundPropertyModel or LoginUserModel. though should not be of significance but want to mention LoginUserModel extends from LoadableDetachableModel

Comment: Also there are memeber fields which represents propertyfields like : private String email;
container.add(new TextField<String>("email", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "email"). Now i am even not able to get the updated value of this memeber variable from the Panel like String email = ((UserPage) getPage()).getEmail();. I do see the value updated inside the form submit of page. I am sorry if i m asking basic question but i am learning wicket

Comment: Nicktar - Please respond. When I pass LoginUserModel to the Panel Constructor, the transient object <LoginUser> is there during Pnael initialization, however on submit when in the Panel, the transientobject is null in LoginUserModel. I have passed to the Panel constructor like PagePanel(...., final IModel<LoginUser> smodel) . Please suggest the directionfrom here

Comment: @user1521828 Please don't rush. In Wicket you provide a Model (backed by an object) to a form or field. Wicket takes care of updating the model values. So it doesn't matter from where you access this object as long as it is the same instance. As for which object... Wicket handles wrapped models transparently so basically that doesn't matter either but based on my personal preferences, I'd use the LoginUserModel. If the model isn't updated, there must be something strange in your code. Can you add your onSubmit method to your question?